# Does an iPhone 3GS running iOS 6.1.6 require SIM card setup after iTunes restore?

Tags: ios, restore, iphone

A few days ago, I bought a used iPhone 3GS. I need to restore it, because I bought it broken and when I disassembled it and cleaned it up, some how it worked again, so the seller didn't have the opportunity to restore it. Sometimes (I can't remember which models and/or iOS version) after I restore an iPhone, when I'm setting it up again, it requires a SIM card inside, it doesn't have to be active, but it has too be there. The problem is that I can't get the SIM card slot in this iPhone to read the card I have. I don't think that it's the card, as it worked in an old 1st Gen iPhone I have, but it won't ever change from "No SIM" to even "Searching..." in the status bar when the card is inserted in the 3GS.

So, my question is: If I restore this iPhone 3GS, will it require a SIM card in order to set it up again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, the SIM card slot decided to work about a day before I did the restore. I don't what did it or why it happened, but anyways it works. To answer my own question: No, nowhere in the setup for iOS 6.1.6 after the restore require a SIM card for activation, I'm not so sure about other iPhone models running other iOS versions, though.